How to avoid creating answer list at front of exam when using exam.tex in exams2pdf
Is there anyway to not produce the answer list at the front of the PDF. For example, when I use
exams2pdf(list(
    "boxplots.Rmd",
    c("tstat.Rmd", "ttest.Rmd", "confint.Rmd"),
    c("regression.Rmd", "anova.Rmd"),
    "scatterplot.Rmd",
    "relfreq.Rmd"
  ),
  template = c("templates/exam.tex", "templates/solution.tex"),
)

I want too loose this part...

In my applied case, I have inserted boxes next to each possible answer choice. I wont be machine reading the answer sheets and I believe it will be easier for the students to complete the exam by marking the box directly next to the question text.

Please show the intermediate .tex file

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it is the default exam.tex file in the exams R package

That block is generated if the template file contains the line %% \exinput{questionnaire}.  Just delete that line from your copy of the template, and you won't get it.

Further details regarding the setup of the LaTeX template is provided in the oldest package vignette, see Section 3 of vignette("exams", package = "exams").
